Problems about packing pyobjc-core with nix
I want to use pyobjc on macos. So I create a package with like this:
let
  newPython = pkgs.python312.override
    {
      self = newPython;
      packageOverrides = pself: psuper: {
        pyobjc-core = pself.buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "pyobjc-core";
          version = "10.3.1";
          format = "wheel";
          src = fetchurl {
            url = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/8b/341571ac5d625968083cbd718e1af7eac54197ed3d404dfff9467c3a8c88/pyobjc_core-10.3.1-cp313-cp313-macosx_10_13_universal2.whl";
            hash = "sha256-JYHo5oiFvLDhHsYZ6B7yjgjuP6xN4g2MyDvFr1vPSpA=";
          };
        };
      };
    };
in
{
  home.packages = with pkgs;
    [
      (newPython.withPackages
        (pypkg: with pypkg; [
          pyobjc-core
        ]))
    ];
}

I use home-manager switch, the install is correct. But import objc in python interpreter complains:

Python 3.12.5 (main, Aug  6 2024, 19:08:49) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nix/store/w599jwl16xzzbm8vdrw5mwm2fanb2yvh-python3-3.12.5-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _objc
ImportError: cannot import name '_objc' from partially initialized module 'objc' (most likely due to a circular import) (/nix/store/w599jwl16xzzbm8vdrw5mwm2fanb2yvh-python3-3.12.5-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/__init__.py)

This is the pyobjc-core packge content. It seems that _objc is a shared library.
__init__.py          _compat.py               _convenience_nsdecimal.py     _descriptors.py        _machsignals.cpython-313-darwin.so  _pythonify.py
__pycache__          _context.py              _convenience_nsdictionary.py  _dyld.py               _new.py                             _structtype.py
_bridges.py          _convenience.py          _convenience_nsobject.py      _framework.py          _objc.cpython-313-darwin.so         _transform.py
_bridgesupport.py    _convenience_mapping.py  _convenience_nsset.py         _informal_protocol.py  _properties.py                      simd.py
_callable_docstr.py  _convenience_nsarray.py  _convenience_nsstring.py      _lazyimport.py         _protocols.py
_category.py         _convenience_nsdata.py   _convenience_sequence.py      _locking.py            _pycoder.py

Install the pyobjc-core without nix just works fine. (On macos, system python 3.9, installed with pip)
Any help? THX
